# Query with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select from a SQL query that gives me all the active employees and the terminated employees that's been terminated 30 days ago?

My table is tblEmpl and my estatus= 'A' is the employee status for active and 'T' for terminated

and the `tdate = termdate`

```
select *
from tblEmpl
where estatus = 'A' and estatus = 'T' and tdate >= '2022-02-14';
```

This doesn't work.

Data:

| Name | Estatus | TermDate | Work |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | A |  | CAR |
| Jill | I |  | CAR |
| Dill | T | 2022-02-24 | CAR |
| PHil | T | 2022-02-14 | CAR |

Comment: You should always aim to provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results - this provides clarity, and ensures your question is complete and working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic as described requires an `OR` of the estatuses, not an `AND`, but an `AND` with tdate and estatus 'T' e.g.

```
select *
from tblEmpl
where (estatus = 'A' or (estatus = 'T' and tdate >= '2022-02-14'));
```

Comment: This doesn't get my actives just the terminated

Comment: This is real employee data thats why I didn't provide and If I select * from tblEmpl where estatus ='A' it gives me all the active employees it seem to me the only thing it's finding is the the tdate>='2022-02-14'